# how to revert commits by other account

Tags: git, github

I forked repo from `origin/master` to my `lg/master` but I don`t have origin master account, now I need to revert a commit from `origin/master` which was already merged to it. 
Since My account was added to the dev group, so I guess I was authorized to revert.

But I don`t know how to do that step by step. I am new to git, so any advice?

When I run `git remote -v`, it shows

```
  lg        git@github.com:Logan676/seadroid.git (fetch)
  lg        git@github.com:Logan676/seadroid.git (push)
  origin    git@github.com:haiwen/seadroid.git (fetch)
  origin    git@github.com:haiwen/seadroid.git (push)
```

When I run `git branch -a`, it shows.

```
  progressbar
* camera
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/camera
```

Comment: I can see the line 

     remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master

in the output of git branch -a , that means that you have origin/master in your local.

Comment: then how to checkout origin/master, I failed to checkout it by `git checkout master`

Comment: This should be because you have two master branches try checking out git checkout origin/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this blog](http://kparal.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/git-tip-of-the-day-pruning-stale-remote-tracking-branches/) solves the problem. Do as below.

```
$ git remote show origin
```

this command allows you to prune all your local branches that track an already-deleted remote branch.
I often remove remote feature branches after the changes have been merged into master and the branch is not needed anymore, in order to “tidy up”. But if you checked out that branch into your local one and set it as tracking, git pull won’t delete such local branches for you. So how do you know which local branches doesn’t exist on the server anymore? Easily, just run:

```
$ git remote prune origin --dry-run
```

and you’ll receive a list of your stale remote-tracking branches. If you run it without –dry-run option, it will remove them for you.

then revert the commit .

```
$ git revert -m 1 (Commit id of the merge commit)
```

after that, you can push updates to remote.